# RobotFramework run single keyword

Tags: robotframework

I am working on a BDD translator in python, where a BDD phrase comes in and a given keyword from the Robot Framework should be executed.
Is there a possibility to execute just a single keyword?

Answer (score 0):

No, robot doesn't provide a way to run a keyword outside the context of a test case in a suite.